# .NET MVC3 HtmlHelper EditorFor access from different area

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvc-editor-templates

In a .NET MVC3 Razor webapplication, how is it possible to use an `EditorTemplate` which is in another `Area`? (using the HtmlHelper´s EditorFor method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you move the editor template out of the area? If you put it in the root /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates, you can then access it from any area.

Comment: That would be possible, but I'm working with modules (/Modules/MyModule/Views/view.cshtml). So the editortemplate belongs to a specific module and there is no root shared directory. I made a work around by copying the EditorTemplate to the other module, removing the contents and rendering the other one as a Partial inside it... works and no duplicate code :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting "another Area" correctly: You can always directly reference objects by using explicit targeting.

```
MyApplication.Helpers.MyEditorTemplate myTemplate;
```